# How to link the selections in Nattable shown in a custom editor view to the sirius property view in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nattable, nebula, eclipse-sirius

I have a question regarding the linkage of the selection made on the nattable in a custom editor view and the sirius property view. Any ideas, how should i go for it, it will be really kind of you if you can highlight the steps in an easy to understand manner, because i have researched a lot on it and nothing is concrete enough to get me started to solve this task. 
I am attaching two screenshots describing, what is the nature of the issue i am facing and what i want to implement. 
Screenshots> 
1. https://imgur.com/bVqfGc4
In the first screenshot, when i click on the element in the model explorer , its properties show up in the sirius properties view, and they should as that is how sirius property view works
2. https://imgur.com/DKsFQBi
In the second screenshot, when i click on any element on the nattable in a custom editor view containing my nattable, the sirius property view does not respond to the selection made on the nattable in that custom editor view.
I want to implement a solution where when i click on any element in the nattable, its properties hsow up in the sirius property view. 
Your help and guidance in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Best Regards, 
Abu

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement and register an `ISelectionProvider`. NatTable provides currently only row based providers like the `RowSelectionProvider` or the `E4SelectionListener`.

The corresponding examples can be found here:
https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_500_Layers/_505_Selection/_5054_SelectionProviderExample.java
https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples.e4/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/e4/part/SelectionListenerExample.java

Comment: Thanks Dirk as always, really appreciate your will to help!